# Read perl dumped data into C#

Tags: c#, perl, data-dumper

How to read Perl Dumped data in C#?
I write a hash structure into  a text file from Perl script.
I need to read the hash structure in C#.

How do I do it?

Thanks :)

Comment: Use a data format that both can understand, e.g. JSON. Both language have libraries to deal with that.

Comment: Please show us what you did so far (see the *How to ask* page).

Comment: Crosspost: http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1071910 (Similar suggestions given).

Answer (score 2):

Data::Dumper is a debugging tool, not a data storage/exchange tool. You could write a parser for its output in C, but that would be reinventing an wheel by making it an octagon.

Instead, use an existing data exchange format (such as JSON or YAML) for which there exists libraries in both languages.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways to read the data in the text file. One such way would be...

```
string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        foreach (string s in readText)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
```